# How to use React SetState on nested data with empty top level names?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
{"ID":1,"Latitude":"-41.276253","Longitude":"173.283842","Image":"Church.jpg"},
{"ID":2,"Latitude":"-41.267783","Longitude":"173.279114","Image":"Centre.jpg"}
]
```

I am trying to import it so it can be rendered & started with the following code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/home/briefsJson').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        latitude: data.Latitude, 
        longitude: data.Longitude, 
        image: data.Image
      });
    });
  }
```

This doesn't as the data is multidimensional/nested. But every example I've found is using better structured data with top level names.

How can I use setState & render to display this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import json from a js file you would do it like this.

Data.js

```
const Data = [
{"ID":1,"Latitude":"-41.276253","Longitude":"173.283842","Image":"Church.jpg"},
{"ID":2,"Latitude":"-41.267783","Longitude":"173.279114","Image":"Centre.jpg"}
]

export default Data
```

Then import it where you want to use it. Now you can map through the data as you like.

App.js

```
import Data from './data'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
class App extends Component {
state = { Data:[] }
componentDidMount() { this.setState({ Data: Data }) }
render() {
 return(
   <div> {this.state.Data.map(item => <div> The id is: {item.ID} </div> }</div> 
  )
 }
}
```

Maybe you want to change the names of the items, and return a new data structure with less attributes this is how you would do it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/home/briefsJson').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      const newData = data.map(item => {
       latitude:item.Latitude, 
       longitude: item.Longitude, 
       image: item.Image}
      }
      this.setState({
       Data:newData
      });
    });
  }
```

Now if you want to display this data in render.

```
renderData = () => { 
 return (
 <div> 
 {this.state.Data.map(item => (
  <div> 
   {item.latitude} 
   {item.longitude} 
   <img src={item.img} />
  </div>
 )} 
 </div> 
 )
}

render() {
 return (
 <div> {this.renderData()} </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably just be easier to first construct what you want, then do a mapping in the rendering. It looks like you don't even need to do anything to convert it, since the json data is exactly what you want in the first place. So:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/home/briefsJson').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ data });
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map(datum => (element))}
        </div>
    );
}
```